# Flutter TimePicker with Starting and Ending Time

Tags: flutter, time, picker

Is there any option to add time picker with Starting Time and Ending Time.

Like select time between 10:00 to 19:00.

Currently I'm using showTimePicker.

```
var selectDateTime = await showTimePicker(
    context: Get.context,
    initialTime: timeOfDay,
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
      return MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
            alwaysUse24HourFormat: 
            24HourForm == '24 Hour'
                ? true
                : false),
        child: TimePickerDialog(
          initialTime: timeOfDay,
        ),
      );
    },
  );
```

In another word selectableTimePredicate or limit the time.

I found this github issues.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32014#issue-439853644
How can I use this?

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet

Comment: Maybe you can use CupertinoPicker to create custom time picker

Answer (score 0):

I think **showTimePicker** will only return the **Future<TimeOfDay?>**, so it's not possible to get both start and end time from same, the work-around is to use this twice one for starting time and one for ending time, and using limits to stop overriding of each other's time.

Or, you can use something like this... https://pub.dev/packages/time_range or any other time range picker of your choice.